# How do I apply gutters but not margins in Material UI grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have been struggling for ages to get my responsive layout to work! But things go out of alignment when I apply spacing to the Grid container with class=spotlight. How can I apply spacing to the gutters (i.e. between the Grid items within the spotlight container Grid) but not the margins (i.e. outside the grid). Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import MasterLayout from "../components/MasterLayout";
import ContentThumbnail from "../components/ContentThumbnail";
import ContentList from "../components/ContentList";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  masterLayout: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  spotlight: {},
}));

const DefaultDashboard = ({ padding }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MasterLayout>
      {/*Top row with right bar */}
      <Grid
        container
        className={classes.masterLayout}
        spacing={3}
        alignItems="flex-start"
      >
        {/* Spotlight section */}
        <Grid container xl={8} lg={12} item className={classes.spotlight}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h3">Spotlight</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={3} xs={6}>
            <ContentThumbnail />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={3} xs={6}>
            <ContentThumbnail />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={3} xs={6}>
            <ContentThumbnail />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xl={3} lg={3} md={3} xs={6}>
            <ContentThumbnail />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {/* List section 1 */}
        <Grid container item xl={4} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h3">Title 2</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <ContentList />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {/* List section 2 */}
        <Grid container item xl={4} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h3">Title 2</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <ContentList />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {/* List section 3 */}
        <Grid container item xl={4} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h3">Title 3</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <ContentList />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {/* List section 4 */}
        <Grid container item xl={4} lg={3} md={6} xs={12}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h3">Title 4</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <ContentList />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </MasterLayout>
  );
};

export default DefaultDashboard;
```

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Override your Grid items' style:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
//...
  gutter:{
    marginLeft: 80, // or something
    '&:first-child':{
      marginLeft: 0,
    }
  }
}));
//...
<Grid ... item classes={{item:classes.gutter}}>
```

The following grid items have gutters ( 80 pixels width gutters among blue outlines, but the first):
[image]

**NL;PR:** Take a look at this [pastebin](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-u15su). I looked at the Grid API, the classes object lets you customize the inner styles of the component. I added a pseudo-class to provide some spacing to all children but the first, thus adding inner gutters.

Comment: Hi David - thanks so much for your help. I am struggling to implement it for some reason? I have removed all spacing from the grid so that it is only applied by the gutter glass. However, when I apply it, it applies the gutter to all children and doesn't leave off the first. I have exactly the same style as you and I have applied tried applying classes={{item:classes.gutter}} to each of the grid items inside the class spotlight (except the title). Can you think where I might be going wrong? Many thanks again

Comment: Hello again - I have realised that because I have a title, I need to amend the code to &:nth-child(2). But that works now, so thank you very much! I also need to make an amend to take into account what would happen on a mobile device (eg. if the grid slips underneath then you then want to apply the gutter to a different child. I have 8 components and sometimes it shows 4 on a row and sometimes 2. Thanks so much again!

Comment: You are very welcome, Katie. If possible, share your final version in a pastebin( like codesandbox), perhaps your changes may help other developers, =] .

Comment: Sadly my company blocks pastebin and similar sites. To see your answer I had to keep looking at a personal tablet, which wasn't easy! The only difference I think was the use of nth child instead of first-child because the first child in my <Grid> was not something I wanted to remove the padding from. I also added &:nth-child(5) to cater for the 2nd row of 4 items. However I will need to do some additional logic to cater for when the screen is smaller. I think the link below is the answer, but haven't figured it out yet! https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't understand you correctly, but you can try to do something with 'alignItems' prop (change to stretch), or try to use 'alignContent' instead.

This [link](https://material-ui.com/ru/api/grid/) can be helpful.

Sorry, if it's not about what you need, it'll be easier to help with some sandbox demo maybe.

Comment: Many thanks Eugene for your help. I wanted to do this and tried, but I just couldn't get it to work. It could be more to do with my skill (or lack of!) than the solution. Thanks again :)